# How to extend work on a branch in Git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I've created branch A which is going through an extended review prior to merging into master.

While that review commences, I need to create branch B which builds on the work in Branch A (which is frozen at this point).

This looks like the following:

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase branchA
```

Our workflow typically has us rebase to master, then do an interactive rebase to squash our commits into one clean commit for the merge into master.

The problem becomes that `branchB` will not be able to rebase to `branchA` after the interactive rebase (and necessary `push -f`) without unnecessary merge conflicts. If I understand correctly, `branchB` will lose its descendent history when I force push `branchA`.

Is there an alternative way to build on a branch like this in a way that will avoid bad merge conflicts down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing `branchB` onto a squashed `branchA` shouldn't result in any merge conflicts.  Merge conflicts in rebasing `branchB` should only arise from any merge conflict resolution that took place in the initial `rebase` of `branchA` onto `master`.

You could perform your interactive `rebase` to squash `branchA` prior to rebasing it onto `master`.  Then rebase `branchB` onto the newly squashed `branchA`, and then just push the single remaining `branchA` commit up to the remote `master`.  This would just allow you to resolve any merge conflicts in a single rebase.

You can really just do it all in a couple steps, on branchB:

1. `git rebase -i origin/master` <-- squash all branchA commits, but not branchB commits
2. `git push origin <hash of single squashed branchA commit>:master`

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge branchB onto branchA before rebasing off master.

Typically, rebasing off of another branch should be the very last thing you do before you merge into that branch.  Until you're ready to merge, there's no real benefit of a rebase.

Answer (score 1):

> create branch B which builds on the work in Branch A

is

```
git branch -t branchB branchA
```

(see the `git branch` docs for how to set uptreams on already-created branches).

after a rebase of branchA, the command to rebase your checked-out branchB properly is

```
git rebase
```

Git follows upstream rebases automatically and by default, if you've encountered some situation where it can't find the proper fork point (see the rebase docs) itself, post a question about that situation, with specific, concrete details please?